# lightdm login gives blank screen then returns to lightdm

Tags: xubuntu, login, 14.10, lightdm, xfce

After typing in my password in `lightdm`, I get a blank screen and then I'm returned to `lightdm`. I'm unable to find any obvious problems in `/var/log/lightdm` or `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` (though I'm happy to post them if they would be helpful).

Current workaround (but imperfect): I can start X from a console but when I do this, I run into another problem which is that sound is unusable (despite attempts to restart `pulseaudio` and `mpd`). I suspect that the original `lightdm` is locking the soundcard in some way so if I can fix the `lightdm` login issue, it will fix the sound problem.

One other datapoint: From `lightdm`, I *can* log in as a different user (one that's basically in default state) and everything works fine -- Xfce starts up and sound works for them.

Does anyone have an idea of how to debug the `lightdm` problem?

#### Update:

Tried some of the actions from [Ubuntu gets stuck in a login loop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223501/ubuntu-gets-stuck-in-a-login-loop) -- my `.Xauthority`, `.ICEauthority`, and `/tmp` permissions don't seem to be the problem:

```
% ls -la ~/.Xauthority
-rw------- 1 dmcc dmcc 99 Apr 15 21:58 /home/dmcc/.Xauthority
% ls -la ~/.ICEauthority 
-rw------- 1 dmcc dmcc 10584 Apr 15 22:00 /home/dmcc/.ICEauthority
% ls -ld /tmp/        
drwxrwxrwt 6 root root 20480 Apr 15 22:48 /tmp/
```

I also tried `dpkg-reconfigure lightdm` (no change).

#### Update 2:

1. Tried reinstalling `lightdm` with `apt-get purge lightdm` and `apt-get install lightdm` (problem remains).
2. Also tried deleting `.Xauthority`.
3. I've `strace`d the root `lightdm` process (once for my user logging in, once for the dummy user logging in) but it doesn't reveal much file system access to paths in the users home directories.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ubuntu gets stuck in a Login Loop](http://askubuntu.com/questions/223501/ubuntu-gets-stuck-in-a-login-loop)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**tl;dr**: My specific problem was that at one point I had put `exec /bin/zsh` in `~/.bashrc` (no memory of why I did this). `strace` was not able to track this down but `fatrace` was since it could trace accesses for the whole system, not just a process subtree.

**Probably boring details**: I was pretty sure that my issue had to do with something in my primary users home directory since I had another user who could login fine. From my `strace`ing, I suspected that the process doing the file access was not in the same subtree as `lightdm` since I had `strace`d it recursively. So, I looked for ways to trace my whole system to try to figure out which filesystem accesses were different when each user was logging in.

I found 
[How do I log file system read/writes by filename in Linux?](https://superuser.com/questions/226744/how-do-i-log-file-system-read-writes-by-filename-in-linux) and [How do I `strace` the whole system?](https://superuser.com/questions/451496/how-do-i-strace-the-whole-system) First, I tried `systemtap` but this got stuck on an [internal error in `ld`](https://sourceware.org/ml/systemtap/2014-q4/msg00086.html). Eventually, I found `fatrace`. Like `strace`, this didn't include much access to my home directory, but it did have this (perfectly normal) line:

```
lightdm-session(11474): O /home/dmcc/.bashrc
```

Once I looked into `.bashrc`, I saw where I had once messed with it. When I commented out the `exec` statement, login succeeded. It remains unclear to me why I didn't run into this earlier or why my `.bashrc` should matter when starting `X11` even if my default shell is `zsh`.